# Spark streaming getting stopped

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to read messages from Spark kafka streaming. But its getting stopped with below error

```
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.000.0.777:3333
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-34e4907e-cc7f-4630
20/02/14 08:12:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/temporaryReader-63fe1c85-68b8-4906
```

Here is my code

```
package sparkProject;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF;

import java.util.*;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;

public class XMLSparkStreamEntry {

    static {
        StructType customSchema = new StructType(
                new StructField[] { new StructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                        new StructField("author", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                        new StructField("description", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                        new StructField("genre", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                        new StructField("price", DataTypes.DoubleType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                        new StructField("publish_date", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                        new StructField("title", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()) });

    }

    public static void registerPrintValue(SparkSession spark) {

        spark.udf().register("registerPrintValue", new UDF1<String, String>() {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public String call(String t1) throws Exception {

                System.out.println("Value: " + t1);
                return t1;
            }

        }, DataTypes.StringType);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws StreamingQueryException {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).appName("Spark Program").master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> ds1 = spark.readStream().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "Kafkademo").load();

        Dataset<Row> stringTypeDS = ds1.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)");
        System.out.println("Key:" + ds1.col("value").toString());
        XMLSparkStreamEntry.registerPrintValue(spark);
        callUDF("registerPrintValue", stringTypeDS.col("value"));

        StreamingQuery query = stringTypeDS.writeStream().outputMode("complete").format("console").start();

        query.awaitTermination();

    }

}
```

I'm using Spark 2.4 latest version of spark. Then why its showing error that `SparkContext` invoking stop from shutdown hook. In new spark its over-ridden by `sparkSession`. Then why its coming here now.

May I Know friends why my streaming getting stopped ? Ideally it should be running continuously.

Please guggest.
Thanks ..!

Update:

Error after updating code:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Complete output mode not supported when there are no streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;;
Project [cast(key#7 as string) AS key#21, cast(value#8 as string) AS value#22]
+- StreamingRelationV2 org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@3cc053, kafka, Map(subscribe -> Kafkademo, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> localhost:9092), [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@7fdd43cd,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(subscribe -> Kafkademo, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> localhost:9092),None), kafka, [key#0, value#1, topic#2, partition#3, offset#4L, timestamp#5, timestampType#6]
```

Comment: The context is a nested field of the session.

Comment: How are you submitting the job?

Comment: @cricket_007, right now am triggering just from Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've never started the stream by calling an action on it

The Dataset and all transforms are lazily evaluated.

You need to print the Dataset to the terminal or write it to some database or hdfs, and `ds1.col("value")` shows you multiple rows at time, which isn't what you want probably

Regarding the error, you have no aggregations, as the error says. Try append output mode

Comment: Updated code to write to console, but its showing Complete output mode not supported error.

Comment: The console doesn't support that mode. Try another one

Comment: Its working with console, I can see the value on console.